# im trying to make a simple discord.js bot

Tags: discord.js

i am trying to make it so as soon as you type: mememe it will react with: your nickname is now:

my current code is

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new discord.client();
client.login(process.env.SECRET);
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("This is Embed Title")
  .setDiscription("this is embed discription")
  .setColor("RANDOM")
  .SetFooter("This is Embed Footer");

const nicknames = ["dumbass", "idiot", "op", "man", "power", "docter"];

client.on("ready", () => {
  client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: "brave" }, status: "invisible" });
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content === "ding") {
    message.channel.send === "dong";
  }
  if (message.content === "embed") {
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
});

if (message.content("mememe")) {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * nicknames.length);
  message.channel.send(nicknames[index]);
}
```

but i dont know why it does not work it says as a error: Parsing error: Unexpected token

that is all and idk how to fix that

Edit : you guys were useless

Comment: Try replacing `message.content("mememe")` with `message.content === "mememe"`? As well as replacing `message.channel.send === ("dong")` to `message.channel.send("dong")`?

Comment: Is this all your code? There is a missing `})` at the end. Also, what @Axiumin_ said. I recommend you to get familiar with the JavaScript syntax first, there are lots of great tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

I first want to say: Please fix your indents (I did it for you below here.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()
client.login(process.env.SECRET)
// const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    // .setTitle("This is Embed Title")
    // .setDiscription("this is embed discription")
    // .setColor("RANDOM")
    // .SetFooter("This is Embed Footer");

const nicknames = ["dumbass", "idiot" , "op" , "man" , "power" , "docter"]

client.on("ready" , () => {
   client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: "brave"}, status: "invisible"})
})
 


client.on("message" , message => {
    if(message.content === ("ding")) {
        message.channel.send === ("dong")
    }

    if(message.content === ("embed")) {
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }

    if(message.content === ("mememe")) {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * nicknames.length);
        message.channel.send(nicknames[index])
    } 
})
```

The issue was you were calling the mememe command wrong. Above you used messega.content === "..."
In the mememe command you used message.content("mememe"). This does not work. Changes it (or copying the code above should fix the issue. Maybe an idea for you. You could add a feature where it changes the Users Nickname instead of sending a random one.